# SQL integrity checks different on update and on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger, check-constraints

I have a `SQL CHECK CONSTRAINT` which checks values base on a column value (located on a different TABLE -> so FK is not an option).

Basically something like:

```
--Function
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_CHECK_ID_EXISTS]
(
  if ...
  return 1
  else return 0
)

--CHECK CONSTRAINT
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE]
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_ID_EXISTS
CHECK ([dbo].[func_CHECK_ID_EXISTS](MyColumn)=1);
```

This works perfectly.

Now I need this to evolve.

On an update, I would need to make the same integrity check than before `(based on MyTable2.A)`.
But on an `insert`, I need to make an integrity check based on another column `(based on MyTable2.B)`.

As far as I know, neither the `SQL function func_CHECK_ID_EXISTS` neither the constraint CHECK_ID_E`enter code here`XISTS knows if the element is being inserted or updated right?

So the `check constraint` does not seem to be an option anymore...

I had in mind to make an alternate solution with an `update trigger` and an `insert trigger`. Indeed I can set different conditions into `each trigger`.

But although the `insert trigger` can check the inserted element via the INSERTED pseudo table, I think I do not have this possibility for the `UPDATE trigger`.

I mean there is no `UPDATED pseudo table` is this correct?

So is there a possibility to compare the columns of the updated element within the `update trigger`?

Comment: Why are you using a Scalar function to check if an ID exists? What's wrong with a Foreign Key?

Comment: There's a reason `CHECK` constraints normally can't refer to anything other than columns in the same row -- a `CHECK` constraint should logically always hold, and the engine does not re-evaluate them all when data changes (only if the row itself changes). "Cheating" with a function like this almost always gives you an incorrect solution that still allows constraint violations, so don't ever use them for cross-table consistency, since that doesn't really work. Use either triggers or stored procedures. `UPDATE` triggers have access to both `inserted` (new data) and `deleted` (old data).

Comment: @ Larnu  : I check integrity on another TABLE column located on a different base. A FK can only check on the samebase
Sorry I forgot to mention this.